# Can i match array data from userdetail while i lookup in user collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

Here the problem I am fetching, I am set aggregate from User collection and I want to match an array from another collection  called `userdetails`, how can I get matched array result which is `[industry]`

```
 User.aggregate([
        { $match: { $expr: { $ne: ["$_id", req.user._id] } } },
    
        {
          $lookup: {
            from: "userdetails",
            localField: "_id",
            foreignField: "user",
            as: "details",
          },
        },
    
        { $unwind: "$details" },
    
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $and: [
                
                     { $or: [
                        {
                          $in: ["$details.industry", industry],
                        },
                      ],
                    }},
                 
              ],
            },
          },
        },
```

Comment: can you provide sample document or schema structure and expected result.

Comment: in user details collections =>                                                                           
company
:
"company"
industry
:
Array
interest
:
Array
minorityOwnedBussiness
:
"No"
minorityOwnedBussinessCirtified
:
"No"
womenOwnedBussiness
:
"No"
womenOwnedBussinessCirtified
:
"No"
referal_code
:
"Amit2Oeu"
jobTitle
:
"job title"
profession
:
"proffession"
serviceProider
:
"No"

Comment: see [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) question, come back and edit your question with proper details, provide valid json document in question not in comment.